# Generate random number with php must be 5 charachter... Even 1 = 00001

Tags: php

My question subject can be seen easy, but i need something different.

```
$string = rand(1,99999) // echo 1
```

But my need it should

```
$string = rand(---?----) //echo 00001 - Always 5 characters..
```

For example when $string echo "23" it should write 00023 , if the $string writes 2 character left side will be 3times zero - 3 charachter, should write left side 2 times zero - 4 character , should write 1 time zero... 
Logic is always 5 character...

Comment: thanks Paul, i did it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...

```
str_pad($string, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```